# Finding a general formula for moments?

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

The moment-generating function of a random variable $W$ is defined as $
M_{W}(x)=e^\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Find a general expression for the even and odd moments of W.

My attempt:

$$m^{(1)}(x) = xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
$$m^{(2)}(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(x^2+1)$$
$$m^{(3)}(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}x\left(x^2+3\right)$$
$$m^{(4)}(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(x^4+6x^2+3\right)$$
$$m^{(5)}(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}x\left(x^4+10x^2+15\right)$$
$$m^{(6)}(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(x^6+15x^4+45x^2+15\right)$$

We have:

$$m^{(1)}(0) = 0$$
$$m^{(2)}(0) = 1$$
$$m^{(3)}(0) = 0$$
$$m^{(4)}(0) = 3$$
$$m^{(5)}(0) = 0$$
$$m^{(6)}(0) = 15$$

I guess the general formula for the odd moments is just $0$. For the even numbers, I'm not sure how should I proceed with this one I wonder? Any methods or theorems I should apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The moment generating function of a random variable $Y$ is $E(e^{tY})$, which is 
$$1+\frac{E(Y)}{1!}t+\frac{E(Y^2)}{2!}t^2+\frac{E(Y^3)}{3!}t^3+\frac{E(Y^4)}{4!}t^4+\cdots.\tag{1}$$
Now expand $e^{t^2/2}$ in a power series. We get
$$1+\frac{1}{2\cdot 1!}t^2+\frac{1}{2^2\cdot 2!}t^4+\frac{1}{2^3\cdot 3!}t^6+\cdots.\tag{2}$$
Compare (1) and (2) to write down the answers to your question.

Comment: Apologies. I don't seem to understand yet. My first intuition was to find a general formula for the expansion of $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$, but I don't see how that is relevant.  Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Compare the two series. First observe that the second has no odd powers of $t$. It follows that $E(Y^k)=0$ for all odd $k$. Now look at even $k$, say $k=2$. The coefficient of $t^2$ in the first is $E(Y^2)/2!$. The coefficient of $t^2$ in the second is $1/2$. Set them equal to each other we get $E(Y^2)=1$.  Now go on to the coefficients of $t^4$. Equating them will give you $E(Y^4)$. And so on.

Comment: Aaah oh dear. I see it now. Much obliged!

Comment: The idea you had, which is essentially to keep differentiating $e^{t^2/2}$ and evaluating at $t=0$, was quite reasonable. Unfortunately, as you saw, we get a bit of a mess. But we can immediately write down the right Taylor series by looking at the known expansion of $e^x$. This bypasses all the painful differentiations.

Comment: Is it fair to say that that the moment-generating function of$ W = E(e^{Wt}) = e^\frac{t^2}{2}$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the first sentence of your post says, except that I used the traditional letter $t$ for the variable, instead of using the less traditional $x$.